# If file is not called "somename.php" then redirect

Tags: php, loops, redirect, location

I have a php file that is included in every other page, that's why I want to modify the code so it's not going to loop forever.

Basically I want to redirect from any other page if the user is not a member to a splash page, the error comes when we reach splash.php and it executes the same redirect again and again (infinite loop).

So I want to modify the code to execute only if the current page is NOT `splash.php`

Thanks

```
if (!isMember()) {
    header('Location: ' . MY_URL_ROOT . 'splash.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should suffice:

```
if (!isMember() && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != MY_URL_ROOT . 'splash.php') {
    header('Location: ' . MY_URL_ROOT . 'splash.php');
    exit();
}
```

Incidentally, you should always call `exit` after you use a header to re-direct, unless you specifically want the server to continue processing the rest of the script.

Comment: +1, deleted mine. `PHP_SELF` is better than `REQUEST_URI`, since the former would exclude any query strings.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting a infinite loop so my browser is displaying "This webpage has a redirect loop." How can I prevent it from infinite looping? Thanks!

Comment: @Adrian M. For debugging purposes disable the re-direct and echo out $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and MY_URL_ROOT.'splash.php' - they *should* be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems they are not the same: This is the echo from the index.php page - /d7/index.php - respective -http://localhost/d7/splash.php . Thanks!

Comment: @Adrian M. In essence, you need to make it so that boths parts are the same - obviously your "MY_URL_ROOT" isn't doing what I thought it was, as it contains "localhost" which isn't a part of your URL root. As such, simply change the **MY_URL_ROOT . 'splash.php'** bit as appropriate.